# call to a method from another obj is model´s or controller´s responsabílity

Tags: model-view-controller

who has the responsability to instantiate an object and call a method from it in MVC?

For example let´s say I have my controllerClass1 instantiating a modelClass1. This is a form that I need some data from a second object. So I need to call a method from controllerClass2 to fetch this data. Said that do I have to call a method from controllerClass2 from my controllerClass1´s method or from modelClass1´s method?

Hope you guys understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as per the concept of the MVC (Model-View-Controller) framework, any kind of business logic should ideally be present in the controller layer. The model part is used only to transfer data between the database and this controller layer. Models generally contains the POJOs which are persisted into the database and the DAO layer to execute that persistence.

As per your question, you are trying to implement some business logic by calling methods of your controller classes. So you should call your controllerClass2's method from controllerClass1.